# Wildcard in taskkill windowtitle

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, taskkill

When I want to close the following two (fictional...) applications using taskkill...

[image: Two hello-sayers]

...I would use `taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Hello*"`.

But how about these two:

[image: Alcoholic programs]

`taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq * wine"` gives me *FEHLER: Der Suchfilter wurde nicht erkannt.*, which can be translated as *ERROR: The search filter could not be recognized.*

**So, how can I filter with a wildcard at the beginning?**

Comment: So the difference I see between you two examples is the space.

Comment: Good point, I clarified it (**So, how can I filter with a wildcard at the beginning?**). :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wildcard at the beginning does not work. You would need to incorporate `findstr` using a bit of initiative.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /v /fo:csv /nh ^| findstr /r "wine"') do taskkill /pid %%a
```

So we search for imagenames with `wine` in the name. Use `/fo` to csv format, `/nh` for no header, then search for the string "wine" in imagename, then kill by process ID if found.

To not be imagename specific do:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /v /fo:csv /nh ^| findstr /r "wine"') do taskkill /pid %%a
```

**Edit**

As for the concern in killing incorrect tasks:

```
@echo off
set "images=notepad.exe,calc.exe,winword.exe,excel.exe"
for %%i in (%images%) do (
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq %%i" /v /fo:csv /nh ^| findstr /r "wine"') do taskkill /pid %%a
)
```

Just add a list of possible image names that would contain the title, it will only loop these as per below and not touch the other processes/tasks:

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe"
tasklist /fi "imagename eq calc.exe"
tasklist /fi "imagename eq winword.exe"
tasklist /fi "imagename eq excel.exe"
```

Comment: Wait, the *imagename* you searched for is `notepad.exe` – I haven't stated it explicitly (but hinted it by using a notepad and a calculator), but the windows do not have to have the same imagename/executable.

Comment: @Bowi You do not have to specify /im at all but it will run slightly longer as it will findstr each task. See edit.

Comment: That makes the answer perfect. :-)

Comment: @Bowi, Be aware that with this solution, the search is not limited to window titles, it will search through all fields that is returned by `tasklist`, including Process Name, Session Name, ... so for example if your search term matches a process name you will kill that process too, even it has a different window title. Another dangerous example is if you replace `wine` by `Console` or even `sol`, all processes in your session which have a window (`taskkill`) or all processes (`taskkill /f`) may/will be killed. So It is better use the `/IM` switch, to limit the scope of probable unwanted kills.

Comment: @Bowi, I would suggest you to not try the search terms `Console` or `sol` or any substring of *Console*, If you want to test, replace  `taskkill /pid %%a` by `echo %%a` to see list of process ids that `taskill` would attempt to kill.

Comment: @sst, that is a very good point, thank you! So the solution would clearly be to restrict the imagename and fire multiple taskkill commands, one for each imagename? One could do this with a loop (or simply c&p).

Comment: @bowi, one way is to list all the possible imagenames that could contain the title in a file or in the script itself and loop through it, if the imagename is not listed, it will not be killed.

Comment: I find it very elegant -- if you give the IM to tasklist, you speed up the findstr.

Comment: Correct, hence why I mentioned yesterday that removing IM will become slow as it runs through all processes. Enjoy :)